# Model class name for JoinTable migration method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In Rails guide in [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-join-table), it is wrote:

> There is also a generator which will produce join tables if JoinTable is part of the name:
>
> `rails g migration CreateJoinTableCustomerProduct customer product`

it generates:

```
class CreateJoinTableCustomerProduct < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_join_table :customers, :products do |t|
      # t.index [:customer_id, :product_id]
      # t.index [:product_id, :customer_id]
    end
  end
end
```

That simply creates `customers_products` table, both words are plural.

When I create a model CustomerProduct:

```
class CustomerProduct < ApplicationRecord
end
```

It always search for `customer_products` not `customers_products`

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'customer_products' doesn't exist
```

**Is there any way to make the model refer to the correct table without explicitly specifying `table_name` or naming it `CustomersProduct` :) ?**

It is good to mention that I am looking to use it with `:has_many :through` and not `:has_and_belongs_to_many`

**Also, Why in the generated migration, there are two lines of adding indices with different order ?**

```
# t.index [:customer_id, :product_id]
# t.index [:product_id, :customer_id]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should name your "join model" and join table due to basic Rails naming conventions. The way I personally like is to name join table with its own word (not two other tables' words). Like not `customers_products` but something like `selected_product` or even `customer_product` will do the things. In these cases your model will search the table (`selected_products` or `customer_products`) correctly.

About indexes. For composite indexes the order of the columns matters. Basically if you have `t.index [:customer_id, :product_id]`:

`CustomerProduct.where(customer_id: 5, product_id: 6)` will use your index

`CustomerProduct.where(customer_id: 5)` will use your index, but

`CustomerProduct.where(product_id: 5)` won't use the index even though the index has `product_id` in it

So if your gonna query your table by both columns in all the combinations you need both of these composite indexes. You may see it by adding the indexes and trying `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to learn how your queries would use the indexes.